How do you upgrade linux without harming /home directory?
I have a laptop with windows11 installed on it. Since it was giving me problems with dual boot, I installed linux and grub on an external 256GB USB hard disk. This way, I see the grub menu only when I power on the laptop with the USB already connected. If I insert the disk when windows is on, then I don't see the disk in windows explorer.
Now I want to upgrade the installation to latest LTS Ubuntu. I have created another USB stick with the linux boot image. How do I upgrade the linux on my USB hard disk without harming my /home directory?
I have my entire git in my home directory. I will take a back up of home directory before the upgrade. However, I would prefer to not touch the /home if possible.

Booting from an installer is done to reinstall your OS, not upgrade. You do not need to do that. Simply boot into your Linux USB hard disk (say Ubuntu 22.04 or whatever it is), then follow the official upgrade instructions from
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NobleUpgrades
The gist of it is: Ubuntu has an application you run that upgrades your OS safely. The upgrade process will preserve your /home as well as any applications you may have installed, as long as they work in 24.04 as well.
Read on for reinstalling instead of upgrading, while keeping /home
If you want to be able to reinstall without loosing /home, you would need to once for the first time during installation make sure you partition your drive in a way /home resides ina different partition than /. That way you could erase and reinstall the OS in / partition without affecting /home. At this stage the process is not simple, as you’d have to first shrink your existing / and then create new /home and more the files there. Rather painful doing that on an existing system, and dangerous (have a backup!). May be easier to backup, reinstall completely while creating a separate /home and then restore backup to /home. After that you are good to go. The downside is that you need to plan disk space accordingly to OS+apps and home.
Of course it’s possible your current Ubuntu installation has already done the split as part of the default install, either using partitions, or LVM or btrfs subvolumes. I cannot say without seeing your partition layout.

Thank you. That was very informative. I tried it and it worked.
